# Router not working when moving code into helper file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried to create some organization in my Vue app, so I moved my router confirguration to a separate file:

```
# /_helpers/router.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import MemberDetail from '../MemberDetail';
import LoginPage from '../LoginPage';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: MemberDetail },
  { path: '/login', component: LoginPage },
];

export const router = new VueRouter({routes});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const publicPages = ['/login'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    return next('/login');
  }

  next();
})
```

Then I add the exported router in my main application.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import App from '../components/app.vue'
import { router } from '../components/_helpers';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
  });
})
```

In my App.vue, I try to display the router-view:

```
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app'
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Unfortunataly this results in the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I don't understand what's wrong... I'm adding the router to the new Vue call, so I think it should be available.

Thanks

Comment: from your comments i can see that the file is on `/_helpers/router.js` not on `/_helpers` which your are importing from on your main file

Comment: There's an index.js that exports all helpers... so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: have you tried using `console.log(router)` immediately after `import { router } from '../components/_helpers';` ?

Comment: I found the solution... somehow I had to define `Vue.use(VueRouter)` in the application.js instead of in the helper... strange, but it works when I move it there. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: You are telling Vue within the helpers file to use vue router, but that "modified" Vue doesn't get exported, so won't affect the main Vue instance

Comment: @bo-oz well if router was `undefined` after the `console.log(router)` then there is a problem on the exported variable which you can debug checking your files , anything else doesn't make sense because i just checked the official doc